# Why Toggle class doesn't work after add a innerHTML on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, conflict

Toggle class doesn't work after add a innerHTML on the same page.
If exclude innerHTML works, why?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var html = document.querySelector('html');
        var sidebar = 'hidden';
        if (document.body.clientWidth >= 1080) {
            try { sidebar = localStorage.getItem('mdbook-sidebar'); 
} catch(e) { }
            sidebar = sidebar || 'visible';
        }
        html.classList.remove('sidebar-visible');
        html.classList.add("sidebar-" + sidebar);

//innerHTML (when I add this code, code above stops work)
var str5 = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML;
var res5 = str5
.replace(/title="Next chapter"/g, "onclick\=\"savePositionNext()\" 
title\=\"Next chapter\"")
.replace(/title="Previous chapter"/g, 
"onclick\=\"savePositionPrevious()\" title\=\"Previous chapter\"")
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML = res5; 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to follow priority in your code. you can change code's position and generate body content before use toggle.